# Cannot Access Local Stream outside getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Here is my code

```
    var constraints = { audio: true, video: true };
    var localStream;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( constraints )
   .then( function ( stream ) {         
    localVideo = document.getElementById( 'local-video' ); 
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( stream );    
    localStream = stream;    
   })
  .catch( function( error ) {});
```

This is part of my Video Chat program.

Now i have another function as below:

```
function connect(){
    alert( localStream );
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection( config );
    ...
    ...
}
```

I always get 'undefined' on alert.

localStream is a global variable on this page.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `connect()` after the `getUserMedia...then(...)` is called (after the promise is fulfilled) ?

Comment: JavaScript is not the same as Java

Comment: yes - sequence is fine. connect() is called after clicking a button. And getUserMedia is called when the page loads. Local video opens and plays fine too.

Comment: I'm sure is a scope problem. `var localStream`is inside a function, right? You need to put it outside that in order to have access to it in other functions.

Comment: localStream is declared at top of page. It is global. Not inside any function. That is what is puzzling to me. I tried assigning a random global variable and this also retained its original value, as if assigning it a value inside getUserMedia had no effect at all!

Comment: Is `stream` not undefined? Are you sure localStream is global? Are you using modules, like CommonJS? Try `console.log(localStream);` inside `then` callback and check if it's undefined.

Comment: stream is defined - and the local video displays properly. And localStream is global. I tried changing the name as well. console.log(localStream) shows 'undefined' as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you're showing us.

Comment: @jib - exactly. That is why it is puzzling that the localStream is "undefined" for the connection.

Comment: Either JavaScript is broken or you have a bug in code you're not showing us. I think the chances of the latter are quite high. SO lets you add runnable code snippets, why not add your code that way?